# Selectbox Parent indent

Tags: php, mysql, categories, drop-down-menu, indentation

I have a simlpe selectbox. It's printing out fine, but i want it to indent the subcats
So the layout looks like:

```
Hardware
 - CPU
 - Motherboards
  -- MSI
  -- ASUS
Screens
 - Dell
  -- 27"
Acer
```

In my db the table is defined as:

```
ID - Label - Parent
```

My current code is:

```
<select label="users" id="cat" onchange="showUser(this.value)" style="width:100%;padding:3px;cursor:pointer;">
<option value="">-- Choose category -- </option>
<?php 
$categories = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM medialib_cats");
while($row = $categories->fetch_assoc()){?>
    <option value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">
    <?php echo $row['label']; ?>
    </option>

<?php } ?>
</select>
```

I have tried grouping the results with group by, but it did not work. How do i make it automaticly indenting with php/mysqli? I Guess i should use recursion?
I would like just to indent the lines with -- and not using optgroup please :)

Comment: How about using <optgroups> ? http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/optgroup

Comment: You have an example? :)

Comment: Here is one with HTML4: http://tantek.com/HTML4/OPTGROUP.html The same works with HTML5. Does it cover your needs? In that case I expand the answer for future visitors, ok?

Comment: I don't know exactly. Thanks for your suggestion, but What i really need is information how to indent the categories with php so it will be done automaticly :)

Comment: I've included the DB queries for PHP in the answer, so you can use it directly.

Comment: Careful with the " character!! It should be escaped to avoid problems...

Answer (score 1):

An option could be using optgroups:

```
<select label="users" id="cat" onchange="showUser(this.value)" style="width:100%;padding:3px;cursor:pointer;">
<option value="">-- Choose category -- </option>
<?php 
$categories = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM medialib_cats");
while($row = $categories->fetch_assoc()){
    if ($lastgrp != $row['parent']) {
        if ($lastgrp!="") echo "</optgroup>";
        $lastgrp = $row['parent'];
        echo "<optgroup>".$lastgrp;
    }
    echo "<option value="+ $row['id'] + ">"+  $row['label'] + "</option>";

} ?></optgroup>
</select>
```

Comment: I have tried your solution, but unfurtunately it does not work :/

Comment: Can you provide some output? Some error? I don't have access to your DB or your web server, so I need some more info to see what's wrong and correct it.

Comment: It does not echo any values name or id :/ Just blank select

Comment: Does the medialib_cats table REALLY outputs the fields described (label, Parent, id)? -please note the capitalization!!-

Comment: Could you please try again? I've made some modifications with the column names. Could you post the HTML outputted, so we can track the error?

Answer (score 1):

Using `<optgroup>` is the standard way of grouping select options together.

```
$options    = array();
$categories = $mysqli->query("
  SELECT 
    id, label, p.label as parent_label 
  FROM 
    medialib_cats AS child
  INNER JOIN
    medialib_cats AS p ON p.id = child.parent
");
foreach($categories as $category) {
  $parent = $category['parent_label'];
  if (! isset($options[$parent])) $options[$parent] = array();
  $options[$parent][$category['id']] = $category['label'];
}
echo "<select>";
foreach($options as $group => $option) {
  printf('<optgroup label="%s">', $group);
  foreach ($option as $id => $label) {
    printf('<option value="%s">%s</option>', $id, $label);
  }
  printf('</optgroup>');
}
echo "</select>";
```

I've made a [CodePad example](http://codepad.org/KgHyZJCN) (mocked the db result as an array) and have it working correctly.

Comment: Hmm... When i tri your solition, it's not printing anything :/

Comment: @SimonDuun Sorry, forgot the `<select>` tags. Try again with my update.

Comment: @SimonDuun i've made another update, this time self joining on the table to fetch the parent label

Comment: Still not working, i tried modifying the code, but with no luck though :/

Comment: What about just adding -- instead of using optgroup?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm... Guess i will try not using the optgroup. Seems it causing some problems.
Also found out with optgroup that you can't select the parent 0 in the selectbox?
What about just adding indenting with -- in the selectbox via php?